# How to add external link from Database in laravel?

Tags: html, laravel

In my Laravel project I have created a input field where facebook account link will be given as input. This input will store in the database. Then I create an object of that table and used the link in  tag. i was expecting that this will take me to the given facebook account link. But it is creating a route like this /link. How can I solve this.

This code is for input field

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
                          <label for="name" class=" form-control-label">
                             Facebook ID
                          <span class="reqfield">*</span>
                          </label>
                          <input type="text" id="fb_link" placeholder="Facebook ID" class="form-control" name="fb_link" required value="{{$data->fb_link}}">
                       </div>
```

And this code is for Showing the link:

```
</li><li><a href="{{$setting->fb_link}}"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>Facebook</a>
```

The file is [Here](https://github.com/yasirarafat28/Royaltyexoticcars/blob/master/resources/views/admin/setting/setting.blade.php)

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @finiteloop I just added the code.

Comment: On your controller or View composer what happens when you dd($setting->fb_link) where that is set before returning your view?

Comment: What does ``dd($setting->fb_link)`` print? Add the code in your view and add the output that you see on your screen

Comment: @OMiShah dd($setting->fb_link ) this prints http://localhost:8000/facebook.com. Though input was only facebook.com

Comment: @finiteloop dd($setting->fb_link ) this prints localhost:8000/facebook.com. Though input was only facebook.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Its the client browser that does this. Nothing to do with Laravel or blade*

If a href does not start with a protocol then it is assumed to be local to the current site.

You need to check the link when it is given to you, and if it starts http:// ot https:// then leave it alone, otherwise add http:// to the url before you save it in the database.

Force the URL to lowercase before you check incase they gave HTTP:// or even hTTp://

Answer (score 1):

It's because your URL is missing the `PROTOCOL` ( `http`, `https`, etc. )

You need to append a valid `protocol` with the URL before saving to the database or in your view.

Example, in your view:

```
</li><li><a href="http://{{$setting->fb_link}}"><span class="fa fa-play"></span>Facebook</a>
```

You can also use the Laravel's inbuild validation method to check if the
entered URL by the user is valid or not. Check https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-url